# How to make agenda bulk tag actions respect exclusive tag groups?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-tags

For example, suppose I have the following tags in an exclusive group:

```
(setq org-tag-alist '((:startgroup)
                      ("work" . ?w)
                      ("home" . ?h)
                      ("away" . ?a)
                      (:endgroup)))
```

In Agenda View, I mark items having the "work" tag, then bulk edit them and add the tag "home".

The result is that the "home" tag is simply added, so the resulting tags are `:home:work:`.

Since those tags are in an exclusive group, I expected the `:work:` group tag to be removed, when the group tag `:home:` was added.

This is how it works in regular org buffers. From what I can see, it is also the expected behaviour according to the manual.

Is this a bug, a mistake on my part, and is there any workaround for this behaviour?

Comment: I haven't tried to reproduce it but from your description, it looks like a bug to me.